# select groups of adjacent rows randomly

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table, I want to select groups of rows randomly.

The classic random query (`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000;`
) selects not adjacent rows, but I want to select random groupS of n rows (in my picture n = 3rows).
The following picture is just example, the rows are random with every execution. 
[image]

Comment: So, we could say that you want to return the following: 1. Random rows, separated from each other by at least two other rows (so, that might be 2, 8, 16, 20, and 31 in the above example). 2. And the rows immediately before and after this data set.

Comment: hmm.... 1000/3 leaves us with a remainder would 999 rows suffice? or do you want 1 row with only 1 record? so could we randomly select 333 records and just pull +1 and -1 from the ID selected (but this would allow overlap.  Do you want to allow overlap?

Comment: @Strawberry, the rows are completely random. the separation is random

Comment: The word "adjacent" has no meaning in SQL, because result sets have no implicit ordering.  Do you mean "groups of rows having consecutive values  of the `langid` column"?  When you select these groups of rows, may they overlap?  That is, can you accept 30-32 and 28-30 in your output?  Does your set of `langid` values have any gaps in it (have you deleted any rows?)

Comment: But there is always a separation.

Comment: @O.Jones, a group by langid is possible, and they may overlap, and yes I can accept 30-31, 28-30, the set of langid can have gaps

Comment: If you don't have to use pure SQL for this, don't. It will be much easier in php or c# or some other procedural language.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming langids are contiguous you can select one group with `SELECT ... WHERE id>3*r and id<=3*(r+1)` where `r` is a random integer from 1 to `MAX(id)/3`. Multiplying `r` by `3` ensures no groups will overlap.

You could create a temporary table or subquery by `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(langid/3 AS INT)`, order it randomly, and select the first N of them, then join against this table.

Consider this

```
SELECT id, name, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, CAST(rank/3 AS INT) AS groupid FROM
(SELECT id, name FROM Objects) z, (SELECT @rank:=0) zz;
```

This result set will give new contiguous IDs to the rows in the `Objects` table, so we don't have to assume anything about their actual primary keys. `groupid` indexes the groups.

From this set you can select any number of `groupid`s randomly, and then for each chosen groupid you can find the original primary key.

Comment: Sounds promising - but I can't make the imaginative leap from this to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect - but maybe adequate for your purposes...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;

+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
...
| 188 |
| 189 |
| 190 |
| 191 |
...
| 253 |
| 254 |
| 255 |
| 256 |
+-----+

SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM my_table a JOIN (SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) b ON b.id BETWEEN a.id AND a.id+2 ORDER BY id;
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
|   1 |
|  31 |
|  32 |
|  33 |
| 108 |
| 109 |
| 110 |
| 144 |
| 145 |
| 146 |
| 166 |
| 167 |
| 168 |
| 199 |
| 200 |
| 201 |
| 202 |
| 203 |
| 204 |
| 225 |
| 226 |
| 227 |
| 232 |
| 233 |
| 234 |
| 246 |
| 247 |
| 248 |
+-----+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```